# Custom kerberos tmux doesn't let me name my sessions, help forcing it?

Tags: tmux, kerberos

I can't name my session with this weird version of tmux:

```
(metalearning_gpu) brando9~ $ cat /afs/cs/software/bin/krbtmux
#!/usr/bin/pagsh +x
aklog

NEWKRB5=/tmp/krb5cc_${USER}_screen
NEWKRB4=/tmp/tkt_${USER}_screen

# cp $KRB5CCNAME $NEWKRB5
if [ -f "$KRB5CCNAME" ]; then
    cp `echo $KRB5CCNAME | awk -F":" '{ print $2 }'` $NEWKRB5
fi
if [ -f "$KRBTKFILE" ]; then
    cp $KRBTKFILE $NEWKRB4
fi

KRB5CCNAME=$NEWKRB5; export KRB5CCNAME
KRBTKFILE=$NEWKRB4; export KRBTKFILE

tmux
```

with command

```
/afs/cs/software/bin/krbtmux new -s $SLURM_JOBID
```

anyone knows how to force it to name my sessions how I want with new and -s in this weird wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the script `/afs/cs/software/bin/krbtmux` to include the option to specify a custom session name. Here's an example of how you can modify the script to achieve that:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/pagsh +x
aklog

NEWKRB5=/tmp/krb5cc_${USER}_screen
NEWKRB4=/tmp/tkt_${USER}_screen

if [ -f "$KRB5CCNAME" ]; then
    cp `echo $KRB5CCNAME | awk -F":" '{ print $2 }'` $NEWKRB5
fi
if [ -f "$KRBTKFILE" ]; then
    cp $KRBTKFILE $NEWKRB4
fi

KRB5CCNAME=$NEWKRB5; export KRB5CCNAME
KRBTKFILE=$NEWKRB4; export KRBTKFILE

# Add the session name as an argument to the tmux command
session_name="$1"
tmux new-session -s "$session_name"
```